# Есть ли более удобный способ работать с Python Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enum

Никак не могу понять как работать с python enum. Неужели нужно постоянно создавать экземпляры класса для каждого выбора? Почему такой неудобный формат работы? Есть ли что-то удобнее? Быть может я не знаю каких-то фичей при работе с enum?

```
#создаём класс Choise
from enum import Enum

class Choise(Enum):
    first = 1
    second = 2
    third = 3
```

Создаём 2 экземпляра класса Choise со значениями равными 3 и 1

```
x = Choise(3)
y = Choise(1)
```

Ознакамливаемся с тем, что у нас получилось

```
print('\n')

print('x -', x)
print('x.name -', x.name)
print('x.value -', x.value)

print('\n')

print('y -', y)
print('y.name -', y.name)
print('y.value -', y.value)

print('\n')
```

Осуществляем проверку на схожесть

```
print('x.value == y.value -', x.value == y.value)
# А вот следующая строка меня просто убивает. Самое нелогичное сравнение в мире:
# по логике, при таком обращении Choise[x.name], мы должны получить value
# по ключу x.name, но мы получаем Choise.third ... Как?!
print('x.value == Choise[x.name].value', x.value == Choise[x.name].value)

print('\n')
```

И как изменить значение у уже существующего экземпляра класса? Пробовал по логике `x.value = 1`, но такая форма записи райзит ошибку.

Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще-то можно так:

```
x = Choise.third
y = Choise.first
```

И работать с названием перечисления, а не его значениями:

```
if x == Choise.third:
    print('third:', x.value)
```

---

Да и не создаете вы новых экземпляров, можно в этом убедиться:

```
x = Choise(3)

# Все id будут одинаковыми, а значит экземпляр всегда одинаковый
print(hex(id(Choise(3))), hex(id(Choise(3))), hex(id(Choise.third)), hex(id(x)))
```

Из этого думаю стало понятно почему запись `x.value = 1` не выполнима: объект `x` описывает одно из значений перечисления и является собой константой в единственном значений: один и тот же объект, неизменяемое название и значение

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь картина стала гораздо яснее. А то примеры в документации навели неразбериху

Comment: `hex(id(Choise(3))) == hex(id(Choise(3))) == hex(id(Choise.third)) == hex(id(x)))` (все одним объектом являются) можно проверить как `Choice(3) is Choice(3) is Choice.third is x`.